# Use only select information from JSON?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to use Python to get the latest price of a stock from a stock exchange API using JSON. The response to my request is a full dataset however, and I only want a very small amount of the information.

```py
import requests, json

asksymbol = raw_input("Symbol, please: ")
symbol = (asksymbol)

response = requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?"
                        "function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&"
                        "symbol={}&interval=1min&apikey=demo".format(symbol))
active = response.json()

print(active)
```

In the dataset you see returned in the below example, all I really need is the `"1. open"` from the very first data point. How do I extract that and make it a value in my code to use in an if statement?

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-09-13 16:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "1min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (1min)": {
        "2019-09-13 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "137.2600", <---- this is the datapoint I need.
            "2. high": "137.2900",
            "3. low": "137.2100",
            "4. close": "137.2200",
            "5. volume": "462812"
        },
        "2019-09-13 15:59:00": {
            "1. open": "137.2600",
            "2. high": "137.3000",
            "3. low": "137.2300",
            "4. close": "137.2600",
            "5. volume": "202006"
        },
        "2019-09-13 15:58:00": {
            "1. open": "137.2400",
            "2. high": "137.2800",
            "3. low": "137.2200",
            "4. close": "137.2600",
            "5. volume": "170841"
        },
        "2019-09-13 15:57:00": {
            "1. open": "137.2650",
            "2. high": "137.2900",
            "3. low": "137.2300",
            "4. close": "137.2400",
            "5. volume": "108757"
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the value associated with a given `key` from a map (called `m` for example) you use `m[key]`. JSON does not make any guarantees about the ordering of keys in an object however so you will need to make sure you index the latest time right? If this is the case you could use:

```
def get_latest_open(active):
    time_series = active['Time Series (1min)']
    latest_time = max(time_series.keys())
    return time_series[latest_time]['1. open']

print(get_latest_open(active)) # 137.2600
```